# convert string to number not working

Tags: php

OK, this is driving me crazy, should be straightforward but I keep getting the result 0

```
$string="92.14";
$numericstring=(int)$string;
echo $numericstring; // get 0, should get 92.14
```

What am I missing - also tried (double) and floatval, same result..

Comment: its php, do you need to cast at all?

Comment: I get `92`. http://codepad.org/Iel5QcM3. And if you cast to `int`, how could you possibly get `92.14`?

Comment: I run this code and get `92`, which I expected

Comment: `$string="92.14";echo $string+$string;//184.28` php cares not for types

Comment: its something to do with the string format, the above is for example, if i do settype integer on the string in question it also returns 0. the string LOOKS like "92.14" on a webpage but for some reason can't read it as a number

Comment: are those real quotes? can you show some more code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your code worked fine for me, please check if you correctly added the `<?php ?>`
if you're sure that everything is ok try using this code

```
<?php
$string="92.14";
$numericstring=intval($string);
echo $numericstring;
?>
```

but according to the result you expected the code above or you code will echo 92 **NOT** 92.14, so use `floatval` instead of `intval`
like so:

```
<?php
$string="92.14";
$numericstring=floatval($string);
echo $numericstring;
?>
```

if none of this worked for you try adding `trim()` function to be sure that your string contain no spaces, (as suggested @Alejandro Iván)

```
<?php
$string="92.14";
$numericstring=floatval(trim($string));
echo $numericstring;
?>
```

**let me know if you need more help**

Comment: The code should actually run just fine. Caveats with casting `(int)` or `(float)` are that, if the first character is not a number (probably spaces and stuff like that), then the casting returns 0. Same with `intval()`/`floatval()`. A "secure" way that I can think of is using `trim()` before applying the `intval()`/`floatval()`: `$numericString = floatval(trim( $string ));`

Comment: thats right, but the example he showed above contain no spaces.
**great workaround**

Comment: Yeah, I know it doesn't have spaces... but it could be the case (and I'm thinking that's the case) that he's just simplifying the example and in his script he does get some invisible characters (spaces or even other ones that you could not see on some text editors). Otherwise it should work.

Comment: there were no white spaces but i tried trim anyway, didn't help. Is there any way the period character could be uninterperable.. eg if it comes through as a unicode format or something?

Comment: try using $newString = preg_replace("/\s+/", "", $string); thant use the newString value

Comment: That should replace all multiple white-spaces, tabs and new-lines

Comment: thanks for the suggestion but still no luck. this really shouldnt be difficult Im pulling my hair out..

Comment: please make sur that the $string is not 0 
otherwise just restart your server (apache or so)
if it still dont work, restart your computer, it may be just a glitch

Comment: @ShaunStevens as you accepted the answer, I assume you fixed it. What did you do? It could be useful for someone else.

Comment: i accepted this answer because it is the most likely useful answer to most people, in my comment at the bottom of the page you can see what was actually happening, although ironically my answer contains the problem and demonstrates it nicely, in my string i had html span markup which didn't show up on screen, like wise, in my answer below I actually typed \<span .. > but the editor removed it.. so always check that you aren't missing html markup in your strings which disappears on screen, thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

to parse an integer

```
intval($string) //Output: 92
```

to parse a float (your case)

```
floatval($string); //Output: 92.14
```

Answer (score 0):

turns out that the string contained '' which I couldnt see in the editor i was looking at the string in, of course removing that allowed me to easily perform the math